# Wininet/Winhttp Changes in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, wininet, winhttp

Is there any official documentation on what was changed for Wininet (and/or WinHTTP) on Windows 7?

Comment: changed from? you got to give a base version to compare.

Comment: From Vista since thats the last published article on MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384085(v=VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

WinInet is the networking layer for IE so you have the same version of wininet if you have the same version of IE. If you do not upgrade IE, then you are talking about differences in IE7 and IE8.

In IE8, you have more controls over per-connection settings, and http cookies. If you want to read more you can visit http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpsanders/.

Change in winhttp between IE7 and IE8 is minimal, only one new function WinHttpIsHostInProxyBypassList is added.